# Node.js readline acting weird

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

I'm trying to make a discord bot that accepts input and sends it to a discord channel, but if it asks me what i want to send and i type in sth it writes everyting 2 or 3 times

```
client.on("message", (message) => {

    const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout

    })

    readline.question(`What do you want to send?`, (send: any) => {

        message.channel.send(send)

        console.log(`Sent ${lolsu}!`)
        readline.close();

    })
})
```

Example output:  `What do you want to send?  hhhiii`
I only typed "hi" once and if I send it will be sent three times.

Comment: Ok i now what is wrong, there are more readlines opened than closed, because there are so many discord messages..

Is there a way to close several readlines without making errors? Because i might be closing to many